# How to put layers between an input layer and a "Model as layer"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, graph, model

This works:

```
img = Input(shape=(224,224,3))

efnet = EfficientNetB0(

    weights = 'noisy-student',
    include_top = False,
    pooling = None,
    classes = None

)
for layer in efnet.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = efnet(img)
# ... any number of layers ...
x = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=x)
```

This does not ("Graph disconnected"):

```
img = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
img = Dropout(0.2)(img)
# ^ "Preprocessing" could be anything, Dropout is a simple example

efnet = EfficientNetB0(

    weights = 'noisy-student',
    include_top = False,
    pooling = None,
    classes = None

)
for layer in efnet.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = efnet(img)
# ... any number of layers ... 
x = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=x)
```

The only difference between the two is the "preprocessing". Why doesn't this work, and how can I put intermediate layers between an input and a "model as layer" as shown above?

(Specifying an input_shape and/or input_tensor in the efnet declaration has no effect. In fact, specifying an input_tensor mysteriously causes the efnet weights to fail to load, because efnet apparently then has 131 layers (???) instead of the expected 130.)

Comment: Where did you get `EfficientNetB0` from?

Comment: The second code looks good to me. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else, e.g. the layers between `efnet` and `Dense`?

Comment: @today I'm sure. There are no layers between efnet and Dense. (There _could_ be, but there aren't any.)

Comment: @thushv89 "$ pip install efficientnet" and "from efficientnet.keras import EfficientNetB0"

Comment: Are you using `tf.keras`? If so, use `import efficientnet.tfkeras` instead.

Comment: @today I am not.

Comment: @Nickolas Could you please create a minimal reproducible example in Google colab?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for the problem, though I don't know why the fix makes any difference.

This works:

```
img = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
x = Dropout(0.2)(img)
x = efnet(x) 
x = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=x)
```

This doesn't:

```
img = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
img = Dropout(0.2)(img)
x = efnet(img) 
x = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=x)
```